# Libvirt - adding pool on external drive - no search permission

Tags: permissions, virtualization

I am running ubuntu 18.04.

First off, how can libvirt access /var/lib/libvirt/images when root is the owner and group? Is there another of security letting libvirt access root files in only some directories?

The new pool in on an external drive, same permissions as the default images folder. Via virt-manager I can create images, but it tells me it does not have search permissions. I cannot access the image after creating it.

EDIT: Ok, i figured in out. When mounting the disk from the desktop, it adds the following mount options: (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)

I am guessing its the nosuid tag. When mounting with "defaults" in fstab, it mounts with (rw,relatime) and it works fine.

Comment: You do know you can change the user:group of files and directories, don't you?

Comment: Yes Tom. You are missing the point. By default the image folder is owned by root, and libvirt can access it with a problem. How is that possible? and how is it that my new folder with the same permissions don't work?

Comment: Ah... that’s because of SELinux.

Comment: Does SELinux run on Ubuntu by default? I thought SELinux was for Fedora/Red hat distros, and Apparmor was for Debian/Ubuntu.